# Redis as a queue - Configuration review

Tags: redis, queue

I need to setup a Redis DB (2.8), which i suppose to use as a queue, which means that it's must be fully persistent (no message can be missed).

I'm pretty new with Redis, and i would like a get a review for my configuration:

- I want to use both AOF and RDB persistence models, while `always` will be selected as `appendfsync` policy. According to their decontamination, always is not recommended, but i must select this option as i use Redis as a queue, and i can't endure any massages missing.
- I would like a create a Master-Slave-Slave cluster using Sentinel with automatic failover.
- Redis service will be automatically started after server boot.

Any kind of comments and suggestions will be great. The administration point of view is more important to me (persistence, backup, restore, high availability, etc).

Comment: May I know why you are preferring Redis instead of other MQ application for queuing ?

Comment: We have used RabbitMQ so far, but it has been decided to use Radis instead. I still don't know why, as i'm new here, but it doesn't important for that moment.

Comment: Anyone can help? I still would appreciate a review for my configuration.

Comment: your configuration seems okay to me.

Comment: Have you ever used Redis as a queue?